# Syntax Error: expecting rightparen before

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I wrote a singleton class to keep track of some variables across my application.

I am getting a syntax error that I can't figure out, I am sure that I am missing something simple but it's been one of those days. Anyone see something wrong with my code?

The error is 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before resultNumber.

```
    public static function setResult(int resultNumber, int value): void
    {
        switch(resultNumber)
        {
            case 2: { this.result2 = value; break; }
            case 3: { this.result3 = value; break; }
            case 4: { this.result4 = value; break; }
            case 5: { this.result5 = value; break; }
            case 6: { this.result6 = value; break; }
            case 7: { this.result7 = value; break; }
            case 8: { this.result8 = value; break; }
            case 9: { this.result9 = value; break; }
            case 10: { this.result10 = value; break; }
            case 11: { this.result11 = value; break; }
            case 12: { this.result12 = value; break; }
            case 13: { this.result13 = value; break; }
            case 14: { this.result14 = value; break; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not Java:

```
public static function setResult(resultNumber:int, value:int): void
{
    switch(resultNumber)
    {
        case 2: { this.result2 = value; break; }
        case 3: { this.result3 = value; break; }
        case 4: { this.result4 = value; break; }
        case 5: { this.result5 = value; break; }
        case 6: { this.result6 = value; break; }
        case 7: { this.result7 = value; break; }
        case 8: { this.result8 = value; break; }
        case 9: { this.result9 = value; break; }
        case 10: { this.result10 = value; break; }
        case 11: { this.result11 = value; break; }
        case 12: { this.result12 = value; break; }
        case 13: { this.result13 = value; break; }
        case 14: { this.result14 = value; break; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean you declared method parameters like in Java. I've corrected them in ActionScript way.